# Want two discussion Forum

Tags: nodes

Hello Hiii Again Everyone I Am Creating A drupal website i want to create 2 forum for different topics Mean I want to create a business discussion forum and business ideas forum so in drupal there is only one forum so how can i make 2 different forms in one website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Forum Containers, and then place the Forums in the appropriate container. Topics are then added into the Forums from the add content or Forums page. So basically you need to plan the hierarchical structure that your forums will take beforehand.

[image]

[image]

For more forum features look at [Adding functionality to your forum with contribs](https://www.drupal.org/node/227121)

Tutorial : [203: Creating and Managing Forums in Drupal 7](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/forums)